# Qual a origem da expressão "gato" para se referir a instalações clandestinas?

Tags: expressões-idiomáticas, origem-histórica

No Brasil, é muito comum entre as pessoas chamarem de "gato" instalações clandestinas de algum serviço, seja do saneamento básico ou até de serviços privados como tv a cabo ou internet.

exemplos:

- É só fazer "um gato" e a gente vai ter Internet de graça.
- Lá em casa nós temos "gato-net".
- Quase todos os moradores dessa comunidade fizeram "gato" em suas instalações elétricas.

Qual a origem dessa expressão?

Comment: Na língua escrita, principalmente na norma culta, frequentemente aparece entre aspas por ser considerado uma gíria.  A origem?  Não tenho a menor ideia de onde, quando e como.  Vamos aprender.

Comment: O **gato** nesta aceção é sempre uma ligação, originalmente à rede elétrica [(Aulete 5)](http://www.aulete.com.br/gato), agora, pelos vistos, também a outras redes. Então poderia vir de *gato* no sentido de 'gancho' (Aulete 9). Como o objetivo é obter o serviço sem pagar, poderia também vir de *gato* no sentido de 'ladrão' (Aulete 10). Agora encontrar fontes para fundamentar isto (ou outra explicação) é que deve ser mais difícil: estas coisas tendem a desenvolver-se na linguagem oral e a dexar pouco rasto escrito.

Comment: É comum usar "gato" no sentido de coisa mal-feita: "Vou fazer um gato e pegar a contra-mão aqui; afinal são só dez metros e já passa da meia-noite". Não sei se a origem dos dois usos é a mesma.

Comment: É só uma especulação minha, mas não poderia ser corruptela de 'engate'?

Comment: O pulo-do-gato tem alguma relação histórica com este gato?

Comment: Não encontrei nada que sobre o termo popular, mas apenas como teoria encontrei algo interessante em https://www.mundodosanimais.pt/gatos/historia-domesticacao-do-gato/, parece que transportar gatos para outros países no Egito tinha se tornado crime (para protege-los) o que os tornaram mais valiosos ainda, então começaram a transportar de maneira clandestina/ilegal. Sendo "fazer gato" no mais popular uma "ligação clandestina" (ilegal) **talvez** tenha alguma referencia. (teoria/especulação)

Comment: @Piovezan Poderia ser. Nesse caso estaria a voltar à origem: *engatar* vem definido em dicionários de 1913 e 1871 como ligar ou prender com gatos metálicos, em que o *gato metálico* é um grampo ou gancho, como ainda aparece em dicionários atuais.

Comment: Eu sempre acho que fosse abreviação de "Gateway", como na informática.

Comment: https://dicionario.priberam.org/gato 5. [Brasil, Informal]  Desvio ou prolongamento ilegal de um ponto de fornecimento de energia eléctrica (ex.: fazer um gato). = GAMBIARRA
Palavras informais. Acho que falar em "norma culta" um poco exagerado. Na fala, todo mundo usa termos informais.  Se diz: fazer um gato

Answer (score 4):

Em visita à cidade portuguesa de Coimbra, tive contato, por acaso, com o significado dessa expressão. Segundo a explicação local, quando uma cerâmica se quebrava( a maioria das cerâmicas portuguesas são feitas em
Coimbra), haviam restauradores que "colavam" essas peças, para não descarta-las. A isso se dava o nome de "gato". Existe o Beco dos Gatos, onde se reuniam esses profissionais . Mas aqui, o sentido é diferente do Brasil, onde nós brasileiros entendemos a expressão pelo lado mais "negativo".

Comment: Falta é saber o porquê de se chamar isso de gato...

Comment: Não é preciso ir a Coimbra para saber isso: basta consultar qualquer dicionário; por exemplo [Aulete 7](http://www.aulete.com.br/gato). Tens alguma razão para acreditar ser essa a aceção de *gato* que deu origem à aceção de 'ligação clandestina'?

Comment: Jacinto, eu apenas quis contribuir com algo que achei interessante além do que está em dicionários. Contudo a alusão ao termo lusitano "gato" está bem clara, sem relacionada ao "dar um jeitinho", "emendas"... E como outros comentários acima, também usamos para situações de trânsito e não só instalações elétricas...

Comment: Valeria foi uma boa contribuição sim, mas só entenda que em um Q&A, não debatemos (no sentido de apontar algo), as respostas devem ser objetivas, então acredito que a sua resposta caberia melhor como um cometário na pergunta ;)